# Регулярное выражение: как извлечь подстроку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка, к примеру:

```
"Доллар продолжает расти. Курс валют на 1 декабря : 27:11:2019 - valuta.ru"
```

Необходимо регулярным выражением извлечь подстроку:

```
Доллар продолжает расти. Курс валют на 1 декабря
```

Comment: до первого двоеточия? split() по двоеточию, берете первую группу

Comment: `^(.*?)\s*:` но для таких вещей нет смысла использовать регулярные выражения, если задача решается с помощью того или иного регулярного выражения.

Comment: @teran ,  мне кажется, вы запутались в собственной мысли :)

Comment: @splash58 да, "языка программирования" там в конце было :) отвлекся на добавление `\s*`

Comment: Объясню подробнее. Необходимо получать контент(новости) с другого сайта, автор сайта не против, я буду использовать сайт на WP, плагин wpgrabber. При парсинге необходимо указать, откуда брать заголовок, я указываю <h1>(.*)</h1> и получаю строку, которую написал при создании вопроса. Мне необходимо оставить только заголовок, без даты и названия сайта

Comment: хорошо, раз это php, переведу со слов в код `explode(':',$h1)[0]`

Comment: @splash58 коли он регулярками уже выдерает заголовок, то уж сразу надо часть его вытаскивает и все.

Comment: логично :)   `<h1>(.+?)  : \d+:\d+:\d+ - valuta.ru</h1>`

Comment: `<h1>([^:]+).*</h1>` первая группа совпадения текст

Comment: @PotroNik я не стал так делать, потому что в тексте может быть двоеточие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1>(.+?) : \d+:\d+:\d+ - valuta.ru</h1>
```

Спасибо **splash58** за ответ